# Node.js Understanding, Two Method Chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I my understanding of Node.js promises is still very rough and I guess I am missing some crucial point here, but I just want to have to functions return a promise, so that I can chain them together and have something like that:

```
importer = new require(importers[i].module);
importer.init(importers[i].options)
  .then(importer.run) // also it is possible to give some parameters here?
  .then(function (res) {
    events = res;
  });
```

The importer is simple module with two methods just like that:

```
'use strict';

var q = require('q');
var FB = require('fb');
var promises = [];

var FacebookImport = {
  init: function (options) {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    FB.api('oauth/access_token', {
      client_id: options.clientID,
      client_secret: options.clientSecret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    }, function (res) {
      if (!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
        return;
      }

      var accessToken = res.access_token;
      FB.setAccessToken(res.access_token);
      deferred.resolve(accessToken);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  },
  run: function () {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    FB.api('4', function (res) {
      if (!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
        return;
      }
      console.log(res);
      deferred.resolve(res);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
};

exports = module.exports = FacebookImport;
```

The whole point is to first get the authentication token from Facebook and the query the graph api for some stuff. So these two functions should only run after one another.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that from a `then` you can return a promise, and the next `then` in the chain will only be called once that promise resolves. You can rewrite your code as follows:

```
importer
    .init(importers[i].options)
    .then(function(accessToken) {
        return importer.run(accessToken);
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        events = res;
    });
```

Or using ES6:

```
importer
    .init(importers[i].options)
    .then(accessToken => importer.run(accessToken))
    .then(res => { events = res; });
```

Also it may be worth reading up on ES6 Promises, since it'll be the standard going forward. Instead of using `q.defer()` you'll do something like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    reject(err);
    ...
    resolve(accessToken);
    ...
});
```

Comment: But I don't need to change anything at the importer itself? The way I constructed these promises?
As I don't need the accessToken in the run function, wouldn't it be enough to call it the way I did, without an anonymous function?

Comment: Oh and I just noticed it was working the first way too, I just had my console logs at the wrong places X-)

Comment: If you don't need the access token in the run function then you don't need to pass it in. If you just call it like `.then(importer.run)` then remember it's still going to pass the access token to the run method. Using an anonymous / fat-arrow function allows you to specify different / additional arguments as per your comment "`// also it is possible to give some parameters here?`".

Comment: ah yes, that was a quick thought when writing the question for the future, but I don't need it right now.
So now it seems to work just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

> Explain chaining in Node.js.

```
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('file1.txt');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file2.txt');

readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```